# The controller for path '...' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to publish my MVC2 app to a IIS7.  Running locally works fine, but once I publish, I'm getting an error "The controller for path '/mycontroller' was not found or does not implement IController"

Is there some magic that I missed on published?

Comment: Are you trying to go to the URL /My or /MyController?  Generally you leave the -Controller suffix off the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that IIS's folders were set up incorrectly.  The tip for me was that there was a prefix in the path displayed in there error. (It really wasn't just /mycontroller')